# CakePHP- saving associated model data

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two models .. One is called `Schedule` and the other `ScheduleContact`.

`Schedule` belongsTo `ScheduleContact`

From an action belonging to scheduleController, I want to save values coming from a serialized form for the main model as well as the associated model.

In my view I have the following

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Schedule.start_at', array('id' => 'start_at', 'type' => 'hidden')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Schedule.finish_at', array('id' => 'finish_at', 'type' => 'hidden')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('ScheduleContact.0.name', array('id' => 'name','div' => 'inline-input')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('ScheduleContact.0.surname', array('id' => 'surname','div' => 'inline-input compact')); ?>
```

etc..

The request data comes in this form (from `var_dump($this->request->data)`):

```
array (size=3)
  'Schedule' => 
    array (size=3)
      'start_at' => string '2014-3-25 11:15' (length=15)
      'finish_at' => string '2014-03-25 11:30:00' (length=19)
      'donation_method_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'ScheduleContact' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=6)
          'name' => string 'Jane' (length=4)
          'surname' => string 'Powell' (length=6)
          'address' => string 'Hamilton Hodell, 5th Floor 66-68 Margaret Street' length=39)
          'city' => string 'London' (length=6)
          'tel_no' => string '+44(0)20-7636 1221' (length=18)
          'email' => string 'powell_jane@gmail.com' (length=22)
  'log' => 
    array (size=3)
      'ds' => string 'default' (length=7)
      'sql' => string 'SELECT `Schedule`.`id`, `Schedule`.`donation_method_id`, `Schedule`.`schedule_contact_id`, `Schedule`.`start_at`, `Schedule`.`finish_at`, `DonationMethod`.`id`, `DonationMethod`.`donation_method`, `DonationMethod`.`recovery_time`, `DonationMethod`.`duration`, `ScheduleContact`.`id`, `ScheduleContact`.`name`, `ScheduleContact`.`surname`, `ScheduleContact`.`address`, `ScheduleContact`.`city`, `ScheduleContact`.`tel_no`, `ScheduleContact`.`email`, `ScheduleContact`.`donor_id` FROM `blood_services_db`.`schedule'... (length=852)
      'hash' => string '5f2b2b3a462f6555cb5290fb49c42df04a7948e0' (length=40)
```

Finally I am trying to save the data like so :

`if($this->Schedule->saveAssociated($this->request->data)){`
which is not saving anything to the database, therefore the this if condition is never met.

What could be wrong ? Thanks

Comment: Have you defined the relationships in Schedule.php and ScheduleContacts.php properly? You'll make your life a lot easier if you stick with CakePHP's standard naming conventions (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) ie: Schedule in Schedule.php and ContactsSchedule in ContactsSchedule.php referring to tables schedules and contacts_schedules respectively.

Comment: Hi, yes I have had trouble with conventions when I started using cake but now I am past that.. However I figured it out. check answer

Comment: how did you get your $this->request->data to return in that format. In other words,where the first level of each array is a different model. I have a one to one association between two tables, but my data is not returning in that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the problem was that saveAssociated needs to be applied in the main model. With that in mind, as it was set up above, the main model had a bolongsTo relationship, which means that  `the current model contains the foreign key.`, which is also indeed correct. So where is the problem you might ask?

The problem is that saveAsocciated is equivalent to

```
 $user = $this->User->save($this->request->data);

        // If the user was saved, Now we add this information to the data
        // and save the Profile.

        if (!empty($user)) {
            // The ID of the newly created user has been set
            // as $this->User->id.
            $this->request->data['Profile']['user_id'] = $this->User->id;
         }
```

Which means that it attempts to save the main model first. Therefore my setup was incorrect since the main model needed to be `ScheduleContact`, since the foreign key will be saved inside the `Schedule` model after data in `ScheduleContact` id successfully inserted.

There you go... CakePHP is Great once you get past that learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Your Model-Name is breaking Cake's naming convention. It should be:

> ScheduleContact

A few questions to give you a better answer:

- Can you add the Model Association Variables ($belongsTo, etc)?
- Do you use Containable behaviour?

Comment: Sorry for those typos, in my code, I am following all the conventions.  As for your answer, I can see how that would get me one step closer to 'resolve' the problem, since if I had not been following the conventions, the association would not exist. See answer see what the problem was! Thanks